# Is it possible for Agents to answer incoming web chats via a mobile device?

Tags: liveagent

I'd like for our sales and customer service reps to be able to answer chats away from the office through a mobile device. Has anyone been able to accomplish this? It is my understanding Live Agent is not accessible through Salesforce 1 or any other standard mobile Salesforce app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, Live Agent can only be accessed in Console. This help article doesn't explicitly state it, but this is the only way to handle chats: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=live_agent_set_up_in_salesforce_console.htm&language=en_US